# Structuring Element (Image Thinning)

Tags: java, image-processing

I need "Structuring Element" for thinning an image. Structuring Element is a 3 x 3 matrix values of "1" and "0". I have declared a 3x3 array using following line of code in JAVA:

```
int [][] structuring_element = new int [3][3];
```

Kindly tell me, what kind of order of "0s" and "1s" should I assign to array? I mean if following is my array for example:

```
[0 0 0]
[x 1 x]
[1 1 1]
```

then how I will decide at what place should I put 0 and where to put 1?
I have to perform thinning on a 2D gray-scale image. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can think of it as an array of arrays.

i.e. se[0] = {0,0,0}
     se[1] = {x,1,x}
     se[2] = {1,1,1}

making se[0][0] = 0, se[1][0] = x, se[2][0] = 1, ..

Comment: I want to ask how i will decide whether I should assign 0 like structuring_element[0][0]= 0 or I should assign 1 to it like structuring_element[0][0]= 1 or structuring_element[0][0]= x I mean, on what basis values are assigned to structuring element for image thinning?

Comment: This is not a java question in this case :)

Comment: You can find a thinning implementation here: http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/flatjavasrc/Thin.java

Comment: Dear MahdeTo! It is a Java question. Image processing using JAVA :)